# The job failed. Unable to determine if the owner(xyz\Administrator) of job "abcde" has server access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cron

I had created a SQL Server Job that throws the error that is mentioned in the question itself. I have searched in Google for same and everywhere its about giving rights/permission but not sure from where to give the same or how to give that?

My SQL Server 2008 Account info

Username: (local)

Authentication: Windows

No Password is needed

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the job owner to **sa** user. For me it works all the time. 
There is a known security problem when the SQL Server can't check the Windows users's credentials. Look [here for some guideline](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834124) about the issue.